# Changing Image in PictureBox using a Timer c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to change the images from a file folder that contains the images to be displayed on the `PictureBox`.

What I am trying to do is, after a given time interval in the timer, the image in the `PictureBox` will change.

I have my code but it doesn't seem to work because after it displays the first image, it does not change after that. Please feel free to correct me on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help and advice.

```
public void playImage()
{
    int counter = i + 1;
    string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UI\UI\bin\\debugIMAGES");

    if (counter > images.Length - 1);
        counter = 0;

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Don't post code on images. Just paste the code snipped. You can format code just with 4 spaces before text. Code on images is not searchable.

Comment: `counter` doesn't change. make it class level..!

Comment: It's annoying to have to open a new image to see the code it's much easier to see it normally as typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your list of images and the counter Global variables, Then on every timer tick get an img from the list using the counter and increment it.

So you declare your list and counter as global

```
string[] imges = null;
int counter = 0;
```

Then on the Form_Load event set up the timer and read the imges from the directory

```
private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imges = Directory.GetFiles(@"G:\Pics");
    Timer T = new Timer();
    T.Interval = 500;
    T.Tick += new EventHandler(PlayTime);
    T.Start();
}
```

Then on the timer Tick event you change the picture like this :

```
void PlayTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imges[counter++]);
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imges[counter++]; // better to use it this way.
    if (counter >= imges.Length) counter = 0; // Handling out of Bounds
}
```